# how to export data from excel table into access table which is not the same as excel table?

Tags: excel, ms-access

How to export data from excel table into access table which is not the same as excel table, ie some data is same, some is different, I want to auto extract only certain data?
DETAILS
I have over 5000 students and researchers in my Access database and they are unique to employee/student number. I need to maintain training records however I do not get training records sent to me for whatever reason. But HR does and their Excel database is auto-updated with this information.

The Excel HR database and my Access H&S database both use Emp/Student # as identifiers and our training columns are the exact same BUT they are not entirely the same (ie. they have some columns that I don't have and Viceversa).

I spent the holidays updating my database with their training info so that AT THIS MOMENT they are the same. But come the next pay period they will have an auto update of training and I will NOT. Therefore I want to figure out a way to auto-update my DB with theirs... Would love any help you can offer. I know I know they answer may be staring me in the face but I am new to access and I am asking for help. Thanks in advance!

Japes

Comment: If you read this and think it's a bad question, please comment on why or how it could be made better. I am new to this ... Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can link to your Excel spreadsheet from Access or import it into a new table in Access. Then create a new query that links your Excel table to the Access by the identifier field(s). Set the query to be an Update query and then select the fields in the Excel table that you want to update the Access table with. I would suggest that you make a backup of the Access data before actually running the update query.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I'm saying the same thing that @jhTuppeny is saying, but LINK the Excel table into your Access database.  Call that the "rawdata" table or whatever you want to call it.

Use this "rawdata" table as the basis for a query in access that will either append/update your Access table.  In this query, you can also automate the data for fields that the rawdata doesn't have, or fill it in with DUMMY values that you can manually update in your updated table.